# Nginx: Start Microservies with Fallback to deployment Server

Tags: nginx, microservices

We have the following infrastructure:

- Multiple Spring Microservices (MicroserviceA, MicroserviceB, MicroserviceC,...)
- The possibility to start every microservice independent locally on our development machine
- A shared development deployment. This is our "server" instance. With this, we have automatically always the last version of every microservice deployed on our server.

Since we have now too many microservices to start all of them on our local development machines we are experimenting if we are able to use the shared server instances. We also don't want to reconfigure all microservices for every topic to decide which is started locally and which to use from the server. It should be decided somehow automatically, maybe by a proxy.

We are thinking of Nginx config, which forwards every call to our deployment server, except the corresponding microservice is already running on the localhost.

Is such a config possible? Or exist some better solutions to address our problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in our case following snipped in nginx does the trick:

```
        location @fallback_host {
            proxy_pass http://fallback_host$request_uri;
        }

        error_page 502 =200 @fallback_host;
```

this forwards every missed call on localhost (error 502 - bad gatway) to our fallback_host machine with the same request_uri

And we have to enter the information for every microservice to the configuration: (for example following snipped maps "microservice-a" on localhost

```
     location /microservices/ms-a/ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri; 
     }
```